# Running a javascript function while opening modal window in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am able to open a modal window when clicking on the anchor tag. The onClick function that I am running doesn't seem to be getting called however. I want to be able to have the modal window pop up and add an image to it through the Javascript. The following is the applicable code:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#openModal" class="submitBtn" onclick="return displayPhoto();">Submit</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr height="500px">
                <td id="photo"></td>
                <td id="description">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

#photo{
    width:auto;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function displayPhoto(){
    window.alert(11);
    document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = "<img src="images/characters/gandalf.jpg" />";
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a JSFiddle.  As @Maverick pointed out, you had a string error with your getElementById line.

http://jsfiddle.net/tz1att9j/5/

```
function displayPhoto(){
    alert(11);
    document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = "<img src='images/characters/gandalf.jpg' />";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Way to steal Maverick's rep.

Comment: I wasn't trying to steal.  I actually had the JSFiddle working and my answer drafted when I saw his answer come in.  I only wanted to credit him since he posted a snippet seconds before me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape your quotes in the `innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = "<img src=\"images/characters/gandalf.jpg\" />";
```

Comment: That didn't change anything, it still doesn't show the image.

Comment: Works fine @powanakaab http://jsfiddle.net/t8v9omqe/ - make sure your `displayPhoto()` function is defined before the `onclick` binding is set - put it in the head if you are using jsfiddle.